# ESAPI logger unable to print method name

Tags: logging, log4j, esapi

I am using logger provided by ESAPI logger and log4j.xml file for configuration. I am successfully able to print log message (just a plane java program with main method) . Below is my code

```
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.Logger;

public class App {

    static private final Logger logger = ESAPI.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.error(Logger.SECURITY_FAILURE, "This is error in case of security failure");
    }
}
```

My log4j.xml file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration threshold="null"
    xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="logs/sample.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d,%-5p, %M, %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I am using these [ESAPI.properties](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/configuration/esapi/ESAPI.properties) and [validation.properties](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/resources/.esapi/validation.properties?r=557)

The problem is %M (used in patter layout) is not printing name of method that is writing log message. %M always prints "log" (method present in org.owasp.esapi.Logger). How can I print method name here (main in this case). I tried writing log from different method still it prints "log" not method name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in ESAPI, which I have earlier reported as issue #268.  One fix is to modify the ESAPI source code.

See https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/issues/detail?id=268.